# Which codec is optimal for streaming a screencast with a small webcam PIP?

Tags: codec, quicktime, video-streaming

I need to stream a video feed generated in real time using CamTwist and QuickTime Broadcaster on OS X.

The video is of a fairly static desktop, with some mouse movements, and occasional mild changes (e.g. switching tabs in a browser.) However, using CamTwist I'm overlaying in the corner a small feed of my webcam.

Which codec should yield the best results for streaming live video of such nature?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with H.264, if not because that's what is most commonly used in Flash.